# Any way to set a session variable in a Rails link_to helper without AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, session-variables, link-to

Here (below) I'm able to set the params variable (i.e., `params[:archive_id]`), but I want to do the equivalent in a session variable and without relying on AJAX, which was offered as a solution to a previous question.

```
<%= link_to books_path(archive_id: archive.id) do %>
  <li><%= "See books!" %></li>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas? Open to other approaches that achieve the desired result: clickable `<li>` to `books_path` that also sets the `session[:archive_id]`. Thanks for any help.

(Oh, and archive has_many books.)

**Update:** I realize writing a helper function is an option, but the trouble with that is doing so without over-writing the session[:archive_id] when iterating through @archives. Sorry, should've mentioned that earlier.

Comment: set it in books_path itself ..

Comment: @Nithin Do you mean as args in the link_to? Not sure what you mean I guess. Also, note my edit about list. Thanks.